# WPF DataGrid giving inconsistent vertical alignment

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid

I have the following UserControl with two DataGrids inside:

```
<UserControl x:Class="emb.OrdersControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="200*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="100*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Name="dgSell" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False"></DataGrid>
        <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" Grid.Row="1" Name="dgBuy" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserResizeRows="False" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

I hook them up to two DataTables:

```
class Order {
    public string station;
    public float price;
}
    ...
foreach (Order order in parse_orders(xml, "sell_orders"))
    sell_orders.Rows.Add(new object[] {order.station, order.price});
```

And this is the result: [image: screenshot]

Setting a fixed height just cuts off the bottom of the Station text. Setting alignment does nothing.

Answer (score 2):

Hah. Realized it shortly after posting.

The text I'm putting into it has lots of spaces and newlines before and after (from parsing the XML).